# Why am i getting a connection error when running a while loop python3.6

Tags: python-3.x, connection

Python 3.6

I have some code which is running fine which gets new exchange rates from XE.com and its giving me the error.

```
ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.', ConnectionResetError(10054, 'An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host', None, 10054, None))
```

In the IPython console after running for awhile.

I did something similar in tkinter and never got anything like this it would easily continue getting the new exchange rates. Mind you I was not having to use my phone as a portable hotspot the last time I was running it.

Is it likely to be a problem with my connection or is XE.com sick of me always accessing their site and booting me out?